# Updating multiple imageview for specific value

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have 5 imageviews and I am updating them based on value but the problem is for updating all of them I have redundant code for eacg image updation expect the specific imageView object. Here is example, I have such 5 methods to update each imageview which I guess is not optimal solution.

```
 public void imageThird(int value){
    third.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(value >= 1000 && value <= 800) {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
    else if(value >= 800 && value <= 500) {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.sb);
    }
    else if(value >= 500 && value <= 300) {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc);
    }
    else if(value >= 300 && value <= 150) {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.sd);
    }
    else if(value >= 150 && value <= 50) {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.se);
    }
    else {
        third.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
}
```

So I have 5 like this method, which is not good I guess, the only difference is the imageview object for each image. May be it is silly question I am not much aware about how images works in Andorid.

Comment: how could be a value can be greater-than 800 but less-than 500 ??? you have defined all wrong conditions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to java or android...

```
public void updateImage(yourview, int value){

yourview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(value >= 1000 && value <= 800) {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
    else if(value >= 800 && value <= 500) {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.sb);
    }
    else if(value >= 500 && value <= 300) {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc);
    }
    else if(value >= 300 && value <= 150) {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.sd);
    }
    else if(value >= 150 && value <= 50) {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.se);
    }
    else {
        yourview.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Moreover, all the conditions are always false. But i think his problem is he wants different drawables for each view. Using some list of int could do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is take the `ImageView` you want to update as one of the parameters:

```
public void updateImage(ImageView iv, int value) {
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(value >= 1000 && value <= 800) {
        // this will never get called
        // number is never greater than 1000 AND smaller than 800
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
    else if(value >= 800 && value <= 500) {
        // this will never get called
        // number is never greater than 800 AND smaller than 500
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sb);
    }
    else if(value >= 500 && value <= 300) {
        // this will never get called
        // number is never greater than 500 AND smaller than 300
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc);
    }
    else if(value >= 300 && value <= 150) {
        // this will never get called
        // number is never greater than 300 AND smaller than 150
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sd);
    }
    else if(value >= 150 && value <= 50) {
        // this will never get called
        // number is never greater than 150 AND smaller than 50
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.se);
    }
    else {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    }
}
```

As you see the code above has some logic flaws. What you needed probably looks more like this:

```
public void updateImage(ImageView iv, int value) {
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // i assumed that 1000 is a maximum and 0 is minimum
    if (value >= 800) {
        // from 800 to 1000 make this super green?
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
    } else if (value >= 500) {
        // from 500 to 800 make this normal green?
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sb);
    } else if (value >= 300) {
        // from 300 to 500 make this yellow?
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc);
    } else if (value >= 150) {
        // from 150 to 300 make this orange?
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sd);
    } else {
        // from 0 to 150 make this red?
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.se);
    }
}
```

Then you call this code like this:

```
updateImage(third, value);
```